# auto renewable subscription about iOS

Tags: ios, subscription, auto-renewable

We are now doing  Auto-Renewable Subscription, and now want to know what methods can be accessed through the user subscription information?the premise is that I do not have the situation of the transaction. if there is no way to retrieve the subscription information, want to know how to obtain the current device has been logged Apple ID.

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you are asking, but you can validate the currently active subscription using the receipt as described in the in-app programming guide

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I understand what you have said,but how do I get the user's subscription information without receipts？

Comment: Why wouldn't you have the receipt? Either the device was used to purchase the subscription, so you have the receipt, or it is a new device in which case the user needs to use the "restore purchaes" function and then you will have the receipt